# What is the difference between "deployment / placement" and "location / position"?

Tags: word-meaning, word-difference

Actually, in my language, they are exactly same.
Thus, it makes me crazy when I am writing a formal paper (e.g., graduation thesis).

Let me give examples:

> The problem for placement of nodes at appropriate locations is studied by him.
>
> The problem for placement of nodes at appropriate positions is studied by him.
>
> The problem for deployment of nodes at appropriate locations is studied by him.
>
> The problem for deployment of nodes at appropriate positions is studied by him.

Comment: *The problem for* should be "The problem of".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo That is not my question, but really thank you. I will edit my papers.

Comment: Should "The problem for enhancing ~~~~ " be changed into "The problem of enhancing ~~~~" ? (Not noun but verb+ing)

Comment: He studies the problem of node deployment.

Comment: In *the problem of X*, X is usually a recognized, well-known problem. If studying a particular thing that is not a well-known "classical" problem, you can say "He studies the problem of how to enhance...* or *He studies how to enhance...*

Comment: I understood when X is a recognized thing, I have to use "problem of X". However, do I have to use "of" instead of "for" when I add some description of goals of problem (e.g., "The problem for enhancing the performance of the wireless communication is studied.") ? I know that "for" is the preposition version of "so that", isn't it?

Comment: **problem" is not the ideal word choice there.

Comment: really? many paragraphs starts with "In Ref. [1], a problem that ~~~~ is studied.", "In Ref. [2], a problem for enhancing ~~~ is studied", or "In Ref. [3], a problem of relay node placement is studied". Oh my god.... Thank you for recognizing they are wrong.

Comment: "a problem for enhancing" is not idiomatic. That a phrase finds its way into a textbook is not a guarantee that it is something a competent native speaker would say or write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That which is **deployed to a place** is placed there *in the expectation of it being called upon to perform some task or action*.  It is there to do a job or serve some purpose.

That which is placed at a location is simply put there.